# Rails remote link_to respond with React function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

So I'm pretty new to React, basically learning by refactoring an existing Rails 5 app to use it.

My app is currently using Bootstrap, so my thought was to change the nav links to be remote, then have the js response execute a React render of a function component, so I wind up with this:

application.html.erb

```
...    
<li class="nav-item">
     <%= link_to 'Adventure', adventure_index_path, class: "nav-link", remote: true %>
</li>
...
```

views/adventures/index.js.erb

```
function Adventure(props) {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                {props.test}
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Adventure />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

This just gives a console error of "Unexpected token '<'", obviously meaning that it's not interpreting it as React, so how do I tell it to do that?

From my research I kind of got the impression that this is not the way people do this, however to me it seemed like it was the most straightforward and required the least amount of extra code and is basically just doing it the same way I would with vanilla JS/JQuery.

Comment: I'm not using rails with react. But i know this gem; https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails maybe help you. This gem allow to return react component.

Comment: I'm using that gem but I don't see how that accomplishes what I need.  As far as I know that gem just renders the component in place and can only be used in the html.erb

Comment: This gem allow return a component from controller; https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails#controller-actions I would not fully understand, I apologize

Comment: Could you try changing the extension from .js.erb to .jsx?

Comment: Yeah that was one of my first thoughts.  It just makes it respond with html since it doesn't recognize the jsx extension.  Figuring out how to make it recognize the jsx could be an alternate solution.

Comment: @MuhammetDilmaç Okay I see what you mean.  I'm trying to avoid that option.  I'm trying to actually have a form be presented in the response and I'd really love to be able to use Rails form helpers to build it instead of having to create it by hand as a component and then pass everything as props.